# independence of events $A$ and $B$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, polynomials, conditional-probability, independence

> In [this proof on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma) of the Schwartz-Zippel lemma, are the events $A$ and $B$ independent? My reasoning is that $s_1$ is chosen independently of $s_2,\cdots, s_m.$

> If they are not independent, then why is it correct to claim that $P(A | B^c) \leq \frac{i}{|S|}$

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: @MishaLavrov can you explain why the claim made on Wikipedia is correct? Thanks for responding, too.

Comment: Also @MishaLavrov yeah sure, they might not be independent. But though my claim is a mistake, is it right to say that $P(A | B) \leq P(A)$? Since A may include the possibility that $f_j(s_2,\cdots, s_m) = 0$ while $A\cap B^C$ does not, I think $P(A \cap B^C) \leq P(A) P(B^C).$ Or is this wrong as well?